# Import dependency "clojure.tools.trace" to REPL in Clojure failed: File not found

Tags: clojure, dependencies, read-eval-print-loop

I'm new to Clojure, trying to debug my program with the function `trace`.

I tried this in REPL:

```
(require '[clojure.tools.trace :as trace])
```

But it throws an exception:

```
Execution error (FileNotFoundException) at user/eval199 (REPL:1).
Could not locate clojure/tools/trace__init.class, clojure/tools/trace.clj or clojure/tools/trace.cljc on classpath.
```

*e says this:

```
#error {
 :cause "Could not locate clojure/tools/trace__init.class, clojure/tools/trace.clj or clojure/tools/trace.cljc on classpath."
 :via
 [{:type java.io.FileNotFoundException
   :message "Could not locate clojure/tools/trace__init.class, clojure/tools/trace.clj or clojure/tools/trace.cljc on classpath."
   :at [clojure.lang.RT load "RT.java" 462]}]
 :trace
 [[clojure.lang.RT load "RT.java" 462]
  [clojure.lang.RT load "RT.java" 424]
  [clojure.core$load$fn__6839 invoke "core.clj" 6126]
  [clojure.core$load invokeStatic "core.clj" 6125]
  [clojure.core$load doInvoke "core.clj" 6109]
  [clojure.lang.RestFn invoke "RestFn.java" 408]
  [clojure.core$load_one invokeStatic "core.clj" 5908]
  [clojure.core$load_one invoke "core.clj" 5903]
  [clojure.core$load_lib$fn__6780 invoke "core.clj" 5948]
  [clojure.core$load_lib invokeStatic "core.clj" 5947]
  [clojure.core$load_lib doInvoke "core.clj" 5928]
  [clojure.lang.RestFn applyTo "RestFn.java" 142]
  [clojure.core$apply invokeStatic "core.clj" 667]
  [clojure.core$load_libs invokeStatic "core.clj" 5985]
  [clojure.core$load_libs doInvoke "core.clj" 5969]
  [clojure.lang.RestFn applyTo "RestFn.java" 137]
  [clojure.core$apply invokeStatic "core.clj" 667]
  [clojure.core$require invokeStatic "core.clj" 6007]
  [clojure.core$require doInvoke "core.clj" 6007]
  [clojure.lang.RestFn invoke "RestFn.java" 408]
  [user$eval193 invokeStatic "NO_SOURCE_FILE" 1]
  [user$eval193 invoke "NO_SOURCE_FILE" 1]
  [clojure.lang.Compiler eval "Compiler.java" 7177]
  [clojure.lang.Compiler eval "Compiler.java" 7132]
  [clojure.core$eval invokeStatic "core.clj" 3214]
  [clojure.core$eval invoke "core.clj" 3210]
  [clojure.main$repl$read_eval_print__9086$fn__9089 invoke "main.clj" 437]
  [clojure.main$repl$read_eval_print__9086 invoke "main.clj" 437]
  [clojure.main$repl$fn__9095 invoke "main.clj" 458]
  [clojure.main$repl invokeStatic "main.clj" 458]
  [clojure.main$repl_opt invokeStatic "main.clj" 522]
  [clojure.main$main invokeStatic "main.clj" 667]
  [clojure.main$main doInvoke "main.clj" 616]
  [clojure.lang.RestFn invoke "RestFn.java" 397]
  [clojure.lang.AFn applyToHelper "AFn.java" 152]
  [clojure.lang.RestFn applyTo "RestFn.java" 132]
  [clojure.lang.Var applyTo "Var.java" 705]
  [clojure.main main "main.java" 40]]}
```

I've searched for the docs of [clojure.tools.trace](https://github.com/clojure/tools.trace) on Github.

It says you need import dependency, but the dependency information are for Clojure CLI, Leiningen or Maven, not for REPL in clojure.

(When I'm saying REPL in clojure, I actually mean `clj`, sorry for the vague description)

So I stuck here. Can anyone tell me how to fix this and what' happenning?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're using `clj` (the Clojure CLI), you'll need to add the `clojure.tools.trace` library to your `deps.edn` file:

```clj
seanc@DESKTOP-30ICA76:~/clojure$ mkdir lyhokia
seanc@DESKTOP-30ICA76:~/clojure$ cd lyhokia/
seanc@DESKTOP-30ICA76:~/clojure/lyhokia$ vi deps.edn
<add the library>
seanc@DESKTOP-30ICA76:~/clojure/lyhokia$ cat deps.edn
{:deps {org.clojure/tools.trace {:mvn/version "0.7.10"}}}
seanc@DESKTOP-30ICA76:~/clojure/lyhokia$ clj
Clojure 1.10.1
user=> (require '[clojure.tools.trace :as trace])
nil
user=> (trace/trace (* 1 2 3))
TRACE: 6
6
user=>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Leiningen, be sure your `project.clj` has a line in it like:

```
[org.clojure/tools.trace "0.7.10"]
```

under the `:dependencies` key.  Then it will work:

```
 > lein repl
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future release.
nREPL server started on port 38715 on host 127.0.0.1 - nrepl://127.0.0.1:38715
REPL-y 0.4.3, nREPL 0.6.0
Clojure 1.10.2-alpha1

demo.core=> (require '[clojure.tools.trace :as trace])
nil
```

See [the clojure.tools.trace GitHub page](https://github.com/clojure/tools.trace) for information on other dependency formats.

---

I always start out a new Clojure project by cloning [this Clojure template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template) from git, then adding my changes to `project.clj`, etc.  You can then type `lein repl` to start up a repl session.

Comment: Actually I'm running `clj` rather than `lein repl`, sorry for vague description.